# Parsing a json streaming with pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, streaming

I'm very new on Spark Streaming and I'm trying to read and parse a JSON streaming from Kafka using pyspark. Reading the stream is ok and also I can pprint() the RDDs.

```
 {"Address":"22.79.52.79","AlarmProfile":"-1","Amps":"11.98","AmpsLimit":"90","AssetTag":"-1","AssetTag_1":"-1","Blank":"0","CAN":"0","Chain":"2","Config":"\u003cUnknown\u003e",...,"WattsLimit":"-1"}
```

I want to parse the json so I can use, for instance, my_parsed_json["Amps"]

But I don't know how to use json.loads() on them.

I'm running the script in this way:

```
/data/spark/bin/spark-submit  --master spark://des01:7077 --total-executor-cores 2 --jars /data/dev/2.10/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.5.2.jar test.py pkb01:9092 topicname
```

Where "pkb01:9092" is the Kafka broker and "topicname" is the Kafka topic.

My python code is:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import json

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

# sc es el Spark Context

sc = SparkContext(appName="mitest")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

brokers, topico = sys.argv[1:]
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topico], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})

dstream = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])

dstream.pprint()
```

I would like to include something like:

```
my_parsed_json = dstream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

but I get errors from Spark. Any help?

Errors added:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/spark/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    ssc.start()
    File "/data/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/streaming/context.py", line 237, in start
    File "/data/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
    File "/data/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
    py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o21.start.
    : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
            at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:163)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:551)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:609)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:608)
            at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:623)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please post the errors.

Comment: Thanks javadba. I've added the errors, but I think must be a way to reference RDD objects instead Dstreams. Like in Scala foreachRDD().

Answer (score 5):

Why not just doing:

```
dstream = kvs.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1]))

dstream.pprint()
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to invoke one of the following operations

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/streaming-programming-guide.html

```
Transformation  Meaning
map(func)   Return a new DStream by passing each element of the source DStream through a function func.
flatMap(func)   Similar to map, but each input item can be mapped to 0 or more output items.
filter(func)    Return a new DStream by selecting only the records of the source DStream on which func returns true.
repartition(numPartitions)  Changes the level of parallelism in this DStream by creating more or fewer partitions.
count() Return a new DStream of single-element RDDs by counting the number of elements in each RDD of the source DStream.
reduce(func)    Return a new DStream of single-element RDDs by aggregating the elements in each RDD of the source DStream using a function func (which takes two arguments and returns one). The function should be associative so that it can be computed in parallel.
countByValue()  When called on a DStream of elements of type K, return a new DStream of (K, Long) pairs where the value of each key is its frequency in each RDD of the source DStream.
```

.. etc

One or more of these will need to be invoked on your dstream.

Comment: Thanks for the nice summarized options.