# Cannot read JSON object from socket in spark streaming

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to send a JSON object by socket like

item = {"text" : "test1", "location": "test2"}

Crawler program

```
...
conn, adds = s.accept()
conn.send(json.dumps(item).encode('utf-8'))
...
```

Spark stream program:

```
...
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
scc = StreamingContext(sc, 4)
dataStream = ssc.socketTextStream(TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)
dataStream.pprint()
...
```

In this case, the code `dataStream.pprint()` will print nothing. but if I change the code in crawler to

```
...
conn, adds = s.accept()
conn.send(json.dumps(item['text']).encode('utf-8'))
...
```

The spark program can print out the message sent by crawler. Does anyone know what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the `socketTextStream`.

```
ssc.socketTextStream(TCP_IP, TCP_PORT)
```

This line is a culprit of the behavior. Can you try with `socketStream` method of `StreamingContext` class?

You might need to provide a custom converter object to use this method.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such method in StreamingContext in pyspark.

Comment: I referred this https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html for the answer I posted. I agree, pyspark doesn't have that method. I just checked http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html

Comment: You can try to map the json in an object and process it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777564/parsing-a-json-streaming-with-pyspark 2nd answer in this might help you.

Comment: Thank u for u answer. I change the code a little bit and now I only need to send item['text']